# Crossed homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and denote $x^y$ by $yxy^{-1}$. A map $f\colon G\rightarrow G$ is called crossed homomorphism if $f(ab)=f(a)^bf(b)$.

**Question:** In some matrix groups, can one give a nice example of crossed homomorphism? Or in which matrix groups, crossed homomorphisms occur naturally?